# How to set local notification for more than one values?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uilocalnotification

Can  any one please tell me how to set notifications for different values at different time..

Suppose i have an array of size 4,

For example an array a={1,2,3};

What i want is after every hour it will show the notification for different array values;

For first time,it will show "1",then "2" after one hour and then "3" for third hour.

The code which i have implemented is for only one value which is shown below...

```
NSDate *fireDate = [NSDate date];

NSArray *values= [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3", nil];

for (NSString *string in values ) 

{
    // create notification...

    localNotify.fireDate =[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:[datePicker countDownDuration]];

    localNotify.alertBody = string;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotify];

    fireDate = [fireDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:67]; 

    [localNotify setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber]+1];

    NSLog(@"1");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use a loop, e.g.:

```
NSDate *fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:[datePicker countDownDuration]];
for (NSString *string in values [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3", nil])
{
    // create notification...
    localNotify.fireDate = fireDate;
    localNotify.alertBody = string;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotify];
    fireDate = [fireDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:60 * 60]; // (1 hour)
}
```

Comment: all the notifications are getting printed one after another i want this in a specific interval of time

Comment: I did give an example, have a look at my answer (I added the `fireDate` variable).

Comment: Sir.it is not working properly...you can see the code i have edited above but not working properly...It is showing alert for 3,2 and then 1.....please guide...